# AJAX Request Erroring

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

**FINAL EDIT - ANSWER** : Thanks for your help everyone. In the end it came down to some htaccess problems in changing the url names and for some odd reason, even when referencing the root (./ajax) it didn't like it. I don't know why still, but it just didn't. When I hard-coded the whole URL in, it worked. Ridiculous - thanks for your help everyone. Everyday is a school day....

I can not figure out for the life of me why this is erroring - can someone please cast a second pair of eyes over this - it's probably something really stupid, thanks in advance for the help:

**EDIT** Stupidly I was putting the wrong URL in - HOWEVER... Now I have put the correct URL in, the site just hangs and crashes. Any ideas please?

**EDIT 2** Just to add even more detail to this post, the "LOADING..." div appears, so the ajax definitely starts, and then the page crashes and becomes unresponsive. I have added extra validation to ensure that the PHP file exists. It does. The PHP file is simply echoing out a h1 tag. This is a complete enigma as I was doing a similar ajax request on a home server yesterday and it worked fine.

**EDIT 3** Thank you for everyone's input and help on this so far. Upon further testing, I have removed the data property from the JQuery AJAX request and it STILL becomes completely unresponsive and crashes. Could this be server related? I'm really running out of ideas...

HTML:

```
<input id="pc" class="sfc" name="ProdCat[]" type="checkbox" value="">
<input id="psc" class="sfc" name="ProdSubCat[]" type="checkbox" value="">
<input id="bf" class="sfc" name="BrandFil[]" type="checkbox" value="">
```

JQuery:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){

    var name = $(this).attr("name");
    var ProdCatFil = [];
    var ProdSubCatFil = [];
    var BrandFil = [];

    // Loop through the checked checkboxes in the same group
    // and add their values to an array
    $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(){

        switch(name) {

            case 'ProdCatFil[]': 
                ProdCatFil.push($(this).val());
            break;
            case 'ProdSubCatFil[]': 
                ProdSubCatFil.push($(this).val());
            break;
            case 'BrandFil[]': 
                BrandFil.push($(this).val());
            break;
        }
    });

    $("#loading").ajaxStart(function(){
        $(this).show();
        $('.content_area').hide();
    });

    $("#loading").ajaxStop(function(){
        $(this).hide();
        $('.content_area').show();
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '../ajax/ajax.php',
        data: 'ProdCatFil='+ProdCatFil+'&ProdSubCatFil='+ProdSubCatFil+'&BrandFil='+BrandFil,
        success: function(data) {
            $('.content_area').html(data);
        }       
    }).error(function (event, jqXHR, ajaxSettings, thrownError) {
        $('.content_area').html("<h2>Could not retrieve data</h2>");
        //alert('[event:' + event + '], [jqXHR:' + jqXHR + '], [ajaxSettings:' + ajaxSettings + '], [thrownError:' + thrownError + '])');
    });

});
```

PHP (just to prove it's working):

```
echo '<h1>TEST TEST TEST </h1>';
```

Comment: Try printing out the status code from the response, which in your case would be "event.status". If it's 404 then you might have the URL wrong.

Comment: Unfortunately the JQuery error box only came up with the incorrect URL- now I have the URL correct, the site just hangs.... and eventually crashes.

Comment: checkout my answer code... maybe its work for you... you have not added closing braces after error

Comment: Try using key/value pairs instead of a string for your data to be sent to php. I'm afraid that you are using a concatenation of strings and arrays which may not be that what PHP is expecting.

Comment: Hi @Stouffi - can you write that as an example please? Thank you

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "hangs and eventually crashes"? If you are using firefox (I believe it works for chrome as well) then I suggest downloading the plugin "firebug", it lets you easily watch AJAX calls and see exactly what is going on.

Comment: @Supericy I click a checkbox. It then makes the website unresponsive. I can't scroll, click on anything. I have to close the tab and re-load the page. If I wait, eventually Chrome tells me to "wait" or "kill page" and Firefox just loads the index page where the echo was supposed to be after hanging for about 1 minute

Comment: I juste wrote an answer with the key/value pairs approach. Hope this will help.

Comment: @Stouffi hey pal - just replied. unfortunately, i'm sorry to say it didnt. and i've just figured out that even when i remove the 'data' property, it still hangs and then crashes

Answer (score 0):

Everything is okay but you still wrong...
See at your `data:` properties:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET", // The get ajax type cannot send data as post
    url: '../ajax/ajax.php',
    data: 'ProdCatFil='+ProdCatFil+'&ProdSubCatFil='+ProdSubCatFil+'&BrandFil='+BrandFil,
    success: function(data) {
        $('.content_area').html(data);
    }       
}).error(function (event, jqXHR, ajaxSettings, thrownError) {
    $('.content_area').html("<h2>Could not retrieve data</h2>");
    //alert('[event:' + event + '], [jqXHR:' + jqXHR + '], [ajaxSettings:' + ajaxSettings + '], [thrownError:' + thrownError + '])');
});
```

and change it with `type:"POST"`:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '../ajax/ajax.php',
    data: 'ProdCatFil='+ProdCatFil+'&ProdSubCatFil='+ProdSubCatFil+'&BrandFil='+BrandFil,
    success: function(data) {
        $('.content_area').html(data);
    }       
}).error(function (event, jqXHR, ajaxSettings, thrownError) {
    $('.content_area').html("<h2>Could not retrieve data</h2>");
    //alert('[event:' + event + '], [jqXHR:' + jqXHR + '], [ajaxSettings:' + ajaxSettings + '], [thrownError:' + thrownError + '])');
});
```

Comment: I have changed the request to post and still no luck - it's doing exactly the same thing and hanging. Also - I don't notice anything different that you have done in the data properties? thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Try This you have not added closing braces of error...**

//Add document ready function and remove double braces around checkbox it should be $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){ in 2 places..

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){

    var name = $(this).attr("name");
    var ProdCatFil = [];
    var ProdSubCatFil = [];
    var BrandFil = [];

    // Loop through the checked checkboxes in the same group
    // and add their values to an array
    $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function(){

        switch(name) {
           case 'ProdCatFil[]': 
                ProdCatFil.push($(this).val());
                break;
           case 'ProdSubCatFil[]': 
                ProdSubCatFil.push($(this).val());
                break;
           case 'BrandFil[]': 
                BrandFil.push($(this).val());
                break;
        }

    });


    $("#loading").ajaxStart(function(){
        $(this).show();
        $('.content_area').hide();
    });

    $("#loading").ajaxStop(function(){
        $(this).hide();
        $('.content_area').show();
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '../ajax/ajax.php',
        data: 'ProdCatFil='+ProdCatFil+'&ProdSubCatFil='+ProdSubCatFil+'&BrandFil='+BrandFil,
        success: function(data) {
            $('.content_area').html(data);
        }       
    }).error(function (event, jqXHR, ajaxSettings, thrownError) {
        $('.content_area').html("<h2>Could not retrieve data</h2>");
        //alert('[event:' + event + '], [jqXHR:' + jqXHR + '], [ajaxSettings:' + ajaxSettings + '], [thrownError:' + thrownError + '])');
        });
    });
```

**Or you can use mine ajax request with your changing**

```
var detailGet = 'ProdCatFil='+ProdCatFil+'&ProdSubCatFil='+ProdSubCatFil+'&BrandFil='+BrandFil;
        // Use POST or GET
$.get("../ajax/ajax.php", detailGet, function (response, status, xhr) {
    if(status == "success") {
        $('.content_area').html(response);
    } else if(status == "error") {
        alert('Something when wrong.');                
    }
});
```

Comment: I had closed it - i just didn't include it in my example - sorry . and that didnt work either. still hangs and dies.

Comment: can you show me it live... ? so i can figure it out... or you can use my ajax request...

Comment: i have figured out this.. please add " $(document).ready(function() { " and please remove double quotes around checkbox. $('input[type=checkbox]') instead of $('input[type="checkbox"]') on 2 places in your code... then you will be able to get response... add me on skype for more detail adeelmughal4u

Comment: I'm afraid this didnt work either - could it be server related?

Answer (score 0):

I thin you mistakenly concatenate string with array in your data object.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: '../ajax/ajax.php',
    data: 'ProdCatFil='+ProdCatFil+'&ProdSubCatFil='+ProdSubCatFil+'&BrandFil='+BrandFil,
    success: function(data) {
        $('.content_area').html(data);
    }       
}).error(function (event, jqXHR, ajaxSettings, thrownError) {
    $('.content_area').html("<h2>Could not retrieve data</h2>");
    //alert('[event:' + event + '], [jqXHR:' + jqXHR + '], [ajaxSettings:' + ajaxSettings + '], [thrownError:' + thrownError + '])');
});
```

Trying with an object with key/value pairs may resolve your issue

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: '../ajax/ajax.php',
    data: { // Here I use an object with key/value pairs. If value is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple values with same key.
        'ProdCatFil': ProdCatFil,
        'ProdSubCatFil': ProdSubCatFil,
        'BrandFil': BrandFil
    },
    success: function(data) {
        $('.content_area').html(data);
    }       
}).error(function (event, jqXHR, ajaxSettings, thrownError) {
    $('.content_area').html("<h2>Could not retrieve data</h2>");
    //alert('[event:' + event + '], [jqXHR:' + jqXHR + '], [ajaxSettings:' + ajaxSettings + '], [thrownError:' + thrownError + '])');
});
```

Comment: really sorry to be a pain in the ass but this didn't work. It still hangs and crashes. I see what you're saying though , the array may be causing an issue. I've just completely removed the 'data' property from the ajax request and guess what? it STILL hangs and eventually crashes. I'm wondering whether this is a server issue...

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){

    var name = $(this).attr("name");
    var ProdCatFil = [];
    var ProdSubCatFil = [];
    var BrandFil = [];

    // Loop through the checked checkboxes in the same group
    // and add their values to an array
    $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(){

        switch(name) {

           case 'ProdCatFil[]': 
                ProdCatFil.push($(this).val());
                break;

           case 'ProdSubCatFil[]': 
                ProdSubCatFil.push($(this).val());
                break;

           case 'BrandFil[]': 
                BrandFil.push($(this).val());
                break;

           default:
                // Checkboxes which are not
                // a part of this loop.
                break;

        }

    });

    $("#loading").show();
    $('.content_area').hide();

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '../ajax/ajax.php',
        data: 'ProdCatFil=' + encodeURIComponent(ProdCatFil.join(",")) + '&ProdSubCatFil=' + encodeURIComponent(ProdSubCatFil.join(",")) + '&BrandFil=' + encodeURIComponent(BrandFil.join(",")),
        success: function(data) {
            $('.content_area').html(data);
        },
        complete: function () {
            $("#loading").hide();
            $('.content_area').show();
        }
    }).error(function (event, jqXHR, ajaxSettings, thrownError) {
        $('.content_area').html("<h2>Could not retrieve data</h2>");
        //alert('[event:' + event + '], [jqXHR:' + jqXHR + '], [ajaxSettings:' + ajaxSettings + '], [thrownError:' + thrownError + '])');
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately this did not work either. It still hangs. I believe it not to be an issue with the 'data' section

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("input[type=checkbox]").change(function () {
            var name = $(this).attr("name");
            var ProdCatFil = [];
            var ProdSubCatFil = [];
            var BrandFil = [];
            // Loop through the checked checkboxes in the same group
            // and add their values to an array
            $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function () {
                switch (name) {
                    case 'ProdCatFil[]':
                        ProdCatFil.push($(this).val());
                        break;

                    case 'ProdSubCatFil[]':
                        ProdSubCatFil.push($(this).val());
                        break;

                    case 'BrandFil[]':
                        BrandFil.push($(this).val());
                        break;
                }
            });

            $("#loading").ajaxStart(function () {
                $(this).show();
                $('.content_area').hide();
            });

            $("#loading").ajaxStop(function () {
                $(this).hide();
                $('.content_area').show();
            });

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: 'ajaxReq.php',
                data: 'ProdCatFil=' + ProdCatFil + '&ProdSubCatFil=' + ProdSubCatFil + '&BrandFil=' + BrandFil,

                success: function (data) {

                    $('.content_area').html(data);
                }
            }).error(function (event, jqXHR, ajaxSettings, thrownError) {
                $('.content_area').html("<h2>Could not retrieve data</h2>");
                //alert('[event:' + event + '], [jqXHR:' + jqXHR + '], [ajaxSettings:' + ajaxSettings + '], [thrownError:' + thrownError + '])');
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: *slams head against wall* - this solution didn't work either - and sorry i should have pointed out before that i had this wrapped in document ready